# Upgrade centos 6 to centos 7

Tags: linux, upgrade, centos-6, centos-7

I Have a server that has CentOS 6 as operating system.
I need to upgrade it to the latest version of CentOS 7.

how its possible?
what procedure I need to pass?

Comment: There isn't any supported way to do that, and the stories people tell of trying sound like it's a lot easier to just build a clean 7 system and migrate the configs/data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the upgrade tool looks broken (see https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool). 
Anyway: a major version change may be a good opportunity to question about fs types, required packages... If your system has enough disk space, both systems may be installed in dual boot configuration to ease data migration.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me in CentOS 6.10

```
yum update --releasever=7
```